# Time complexity for storing array elements

Tags: java

Here's my program, i'm able to get the time complexity partially can anyone help me with this:

I'am able to get some of them, but can anyone verify if my approach is right

```
package sd;

public class Max {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i;
        int large[] = new int[5];
        int array[] = { 33, 55, 13, 46, 87, 42, 10, 34, 43, 56 };
        int max = 0, index = 0;

        // O(5)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            max = array[0]; // Assuming max to be first element

            // Comparing 1st element with max O(n)
            for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (max < array[i]) {
                    max = array[i]; // Replace if greater
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            large[j] = max;
            array[index] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // Find max and replace with least
                                                // possible value to avoid
                                                // duplicate max

            System.out.println("Largest 5 amoung 10 : " + large[j]); // Time
                                                                        // complexity:
                                                                        // O(5)
                                                                        // *
                                                                        // O(n)
                                                                        // =
                                                                        // O(n)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should specify what parameters of your code are constant and which are not. Otherwise your code seems not to take any input data, so it is completely independent of input size, so it might run in `O(1)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Complexity here is `O(5N)`.

For further info about finding complexity check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm).

Comment: it has nested for loops , i'm assuming it has O(n2)

Comment: if both loops were same size yes, `N*N = N^2` but first loop is fixed, so `5*N`

Comment: can't we ignore the constants?

Comment: check the link provided, it's explained... anyway... it's how I understand it, but i'm not John Skeet... so I can be wrong... xDD